# Set some connections to not be notified about their activities on linkedin?

Tags: linkedin

Is there a way to set specific connections on linkedin so that email notifications are not sent while allowing the other connections actions to trigger the emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- MyNetwork
- Your Connections See All
- (select specific person)
- More > Unfollow